# MVC Custom Route HttpPost failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

So I have a custom route like this :

```
routes.MapRoute( _
            "Article", _
            "Article/{id}", _
            New With {.controller = "Article", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
        )
```

My Controller :

```
Function Index(Optional ByVal Id As String = "") As ActionResult

            If Id <> "" Then
                //do something
                Return View("ArticleDetail", model)
            Else
                Return View()
            End If
        End Function

<HttpPost()>
        Function Comment(ByVal model As ArticleModel) As ActionResult
            If ModelState.IsValid Then
                //do something
            End If

            Return View("ArticleDetail", model)
        End Function
```

My View :

```
Using Html.BeginForm("Comment", "Article", FormMethod.Post)
```

The problem is that it won't let me call the "Comment" method, instead it calls the 'Index' method with "Comment" As "Id" because my RouteConfig setting. How do I achieve this?

Sorry for bad english, any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE :
I tried adding another route like 'Dakshal Raijada' suggested

```
routes.MapRoute( _
            "ArticleComment", _
            "Article/Comment", _
            New With {.controller = "Article", .action = "Comment"} _
        )
```

It works, but for some reason, this cause it to called my model constructor before controller resulting in null model. Any idea?

Comment: Debugging routing issues is notoriously hard.  Try adding @haacked's [route debugger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/) to your project to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your routing you are always calling the Index method no matter what

Try using this:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
    "Article", _
    "Article/{id}", _
    New With {.controller = "Article", .action = "Comment", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
)
```

Comment is an action and not Id.

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for quick response. The problem I don't want to have {action} because I want my user to only type site.com/Article/{article-name} instead of site.com/Article/Index/{article-name}.

Comment: Sorry my bad but for comment is it fine to have site.com/Article/Comment/{article-name}?

Comment: hello again, please read my edited question.

the comment is supposed to redirect to another View (aka Detail), so the user won't even see the "Comment" in their browser URL.

Comment: Sorry I didnt follow the line where "it calls the model constructor...", Is the comment method called after you added new route? If so, then where is the error?

Comment: yes, the 'Comment' method was called, but before that it called my Model(ArticleModel) constructor resulting my model to have null value before entering 'Comment' method.

Comment: From the view you need to pass the form data which should map to the ArticleModel. See that you are posting the correct data to the method and you can also try accepting FormCollection and see if it passes the proper keys.